# Trying to get property of non-object (View:)

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo el siguiente código, pero cuando voy a pasar valores a la vista me sale el error **Trying to get property of non-object**.
¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

**En la ruta control:**

```
Route::get('test2', function(){

    $client = new Client();

    $response = $client->post("http://Myruta.com/login", [

        'headers' => ['foo' => 'bar'],

        'json' => [
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'test',
        ]
    ]);


    $user = json_decode( $response->getBody()->getContents() );

    return view('welcome', compact('user'));


});
```

**En la vista:**

```
{{$user->user_name}}
```

**Resultado:**

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: ....

Comment: ¿qué muestra un dump de $user?

Comment: [
{
"id": 195,
"email": "test@test.co",
"user_name": "Pruebas",
"img": null,
"user_phone": null,
"user_id_facebook": null,
"user_conf_code": null,
"created_at": "2017-02-14 18:53:19",
"updated_at": "2017-02-14 18:53:19"
}
]

Comment: Bueno, como te puedes dar cuenta eso no es un objeto, de ahí viene el error.

Comment: Ok,  y ¿como debería hacerlo? no tengo mucha experiencia esto.

Comment: ¿qué obtienes en $response->getBody()->getContents()?

Comment: al retornar me devuelve lo que te respondí arriba: los datos del usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que obtienes según tu comentario es un arreglo, con UN OBJETO dentro `[{}...]`, por lo tanto :

```
$user[0]['id']
```

seria suficiente para acceder a las propiedades.

O puedes intentar

```
@foreach($user as $u) 
   {{ $u->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Lo intenté así pero salió esto: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: puedes hacer un `print_r` de `$user` en la vista? edite mi respuesta @CesarAugusto

Comment: Con el foreach si funcionó, siempre va a ser necesario hacer foreach?

Comment: Segun los ejemplos que vi en internet si, la verdad es que tu servicio `http://Myruta.com/login` devuelve un array con un objeto, tu a esa respuesta le haces un `json_decode` la opcion seria que en el controlador armes tu un formato de retorno a la vista. Accediendo ahi a sus propiedades. Al parecer es un LOGIN por lo que siempre deberia devolver un OBJETO y no un arreglo.

Comment: si te sirvio mi respuesta marcarla @CesarAugusto

Comment: Si, muchas gracias. Sobre lo ultimo que comentas de armar un formato en el controlador que me devuelva el objeto, suena a que es lo que necesito. como te comenté no tengo mucha experiencia esto, soy novato. no se como se haría eso en el controlador

Comment: Como ya nombraste en los comentarios, cuando imprimes `$user` en tu controlador, obtienes el mismo objeto, puedes poner en tu controlador lo siguiente : `print_r($user);exit;` y dejar lo que te retorna?

Comment: es lo que devuelve Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 195 [email] => test@test.co [company_id] => [user_name] => Pruebas [img] => [user_phone] => [user_type] => US [user_validate] => 0 [user_id_facebook] => [user_conf_code] => [created_at] => 2017-02-14 18:53:19 [updated_at] => 2017-02-14 18:53:19 ) )

Comment: puedes intentar hacer `$user = json_decode(json_encode($response->getBody()->getContents()), true);` e imprimir array?