# Recorrer objeto

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, blade

Cómo puedo recorrer este arreglo desde la vista blade de laravel, estoy intentando esto, pero no funciona:

```
              @foreach($revisiones as $key => $item)
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ $item->inventario_ram->codigo_ram }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->inventario_ram->fabricante['fabricante'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->inventario_ram->modelo }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->inventario_ram->compatibilidad }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->inventario_ram->tecnologia->tecnologia }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
```

el arreglo que quiero recorrer es el siguiente:
[image: arreglo que devuelve eloquent]

Me lanza este error de propiedad, sin embargo la propiedad si existe:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito de su ayuda, por favor!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Trying to get property of non-object (View:)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88342/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-view)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás tratando de hacer es acceder a la información como si se tratara de un objeto, pero no lo es, es un arreglo.

Para acceder a la información deberías de tener la siguiente implementación:

```
$item['inventario_ram']['codigo_ram']
```

Con eso debería de funcionar